# Is superscript possible in a plain text email?

Tags: email

I have a plain text email that contains superscripts relating to footnotes found later in the email body.

Is this possible to use superscripts in a plain-text email, or do I have to go with html? Or, are some other symbols acceptable in this situation?

Comment: This question isn't so much about superscripts as it is about how to represent footnotes in e-mail.

Comment: Either way, nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

Comment: @T.E.D I'm sending the email via code, so it has very much to do with programming.

Comment: "Is superscript possible in a plain text email? for programmers!!1"

Comment: Your question is about email formatting conventions. Not about how to write code that sends emails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd either have to use HTML, or a format like:

> This is an assertion[1] with a
>   footnote.
>
> [1] See?  A footnote!

Comment: This is very commonly used and easy to understand even if you've never seen it before.

Comment: I'd like to suggest *not* putting footnotes all the way at the bottom of a message. Instead, put it immediately following the paragraph where the footnote marker appeared. That way, it's easy to jump to and easy to jump back from. Scrolling up and down an e-mail message isn't like jumping up and down a printed page.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try to use Unicode superscripted numerals, but on the whole, you'd be better off with the [n] notation recommended by VoteyDisciple.